# Why does my "Add New Post" page have an old post in it?

Tags: posts, templates

I created a brand new WordPress site.

I imported the export *.xml from my old site.

Now, when I go to "Add New Post", there is an old post in there, and I can't seem to do anything without getting an InvalidID error.

Here's a look:

[image: Why is there data in my editor?]

FWIW, the entry that shows up has a very large ID value: 9223372036854775809

**ADDED:** It also happens on my "Add New Page" screen.

Comment: If you have access to database, check ID values in wp_posts table. Are they really such big numbers? If you have your old site database, check values there as well. Maybe you have problem with export/import messing up post IDs.

Comment: There is a set of posts that have huge post IDs.  But they are set to those values in the XML.  Thanks for taking the time to help.